# What do the Optometrist eyeglass prescription numbers mean?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

I want to know what the numbers mean in my eye glasses prescription.  The top 50 google hits give overly simplistic answers.

For example

```
eye  Sphere   Cylinder   Axis      Add
OD   +3.00     -1.00     100       1.50
OS   +2.50     -0.50     078       1.50
```

Here is my best guess. Please confirm or deny.

- OD=right eye, OS=left eye.
- **Sphere** is diopter, which is one over focal len (in meters).
- **Cylinder** is also diopter and it is added to the sphere
- **Axis** is the direction of the cylinder axis in degrees: 0 is horizontal, 45 is patient upper-left to lower-right, 90 is vertical.
- **Add** is for bifocals

In this example, the focal length of the right eye lens along the 100-degree axis will be 1/3 meters. And the focal length along the right eye lens along the 10-degree axis will be 1/2 meters.  Is that correct?

Comment: You seem to have astigmatism.  However, it is important to note that there may be a hidden assumption here that all optometrists use the same equipment, take the same measurements, and label those measurements consistently across that industry.  I suggest you ask your individual optometrist for an explanation of the measurements.

Comment: ADD is addition of so many diopters for near vision and  you probably have a DV (distance vision) and an NV (near vision) symbol somewhere on the prescription for a multifocal (bifocal) lens.